# Python Pandas - SequenceMatch columns for each value and return closet match

Tags: python, string, pandas, string-comparison

I have two `DataFrame` objects containing 2 columns of string data each.  I need to compare columns `a` and `b` with `c` and `d` then merge the two `DataFrame` objects based on the highest match ratio.

```
   DF1                                DF2
a       b                          c       d
apple  paster                      doser   ankle
bac    bur                         are     bun
sit    sign                        and     lake
car    bun                         ape     mason
alli   makeup                      noodle  paster
```

## EXAMPLE OUTPUT

```
          RESULT                               
a       b       c       d       comparison_ratio
apple  paster  noodle  paster   1
bac    bur     are     bun      0.95
sit    sign    and     lake     random number based on match
car    bun     are     bun      1
alli   makeup  noodle  paster   random number based on match
```

Obviously the ratios are made up aside from perfect match 1.

I could loop through each line of each `DataFrame` object and apply the `difflib.SequenceMatcher` function to return the ratio and then take the max ratio along with the corresponding data to set the value on that line, but given how large the data is this would take a very long time.  I am curious if I can somehow use `apply` to apply this function across the two `DataFrame` objects

Answer (score 3):

(Did some of your output change between the original `df2` and the example output? I'm assuming the example output has the correct `df2`.) It looks like you're pairing `a` to `c` and `b` to `d` row by row, so first, let's just concatenate the dataframes together.

```
import pandas as pd
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['apple', 'bac', 'sit', 'car', 'alli'],
                    'b': ['paster', 'bur', 'sign', 'bun', 'makeup']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c': ['noodle', 'are', 'and', 'ape', 'noodle'],
                    'd': ['paster', 'bun', 'lake', 'bun', 'paster']})

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

We have to do an `apply` that takes in two columns. We should make a function that can take in the two column names as arguments.

```
def sim_metric(df, col1, col2):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, df[col1], df[col2]).ratio()
```

I had to look up how `SequenceMatcher` works. One thing to note is that it can take in arrays, so you have to be careful: you are specifically interested in *string* sequence matching, element to element—which is why you need `apply` and can't directly plug in the columns.

Now you can apply this `sim_metric` to `a` and `c` and to `b` and `d`.

```
df['a_c_comp'] = df.apply(sim_metric,
                          args=('a', 'c'),
                          axis=1)

df['b_d_comp'] = df.apply(sim_metric,
                          args=('b', 'd'),
                          axis=1)
```

Note how I used the `args` arg of `apply` to specify the column names for the generic `sim_metric`.

Finally, we can do the `max` for the final `comparison_ratio` column.

```
df['comparison_ratio'] = df[['a_c_comp', 'b_d_comp']].max(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Here's the result.

```
       a       b       c       d  a_c_comp  b_d_comp  comparison_ratio
0  apple  paster  noodle  paster  0.363636  1.000000          1.000000
1    bac     bur     are     bun  0.333333  0.666667          0.666667
2    sit    sign     and    lake  0.000000  0.000000          0.000000
3    car     bun     ape     bun  0.333333  1.000000          1.000000
4   alli  makeup  noodle  paster  0.200000  0.333333          0.333333
```

Comment: This seems to be simply a check between the dataframe columns as they stand.  I need to check column a index 1 against all items in column c and column d then find the maximum match ratio and concatenate the max match ratio values from c and d to that row. That is why the result df changed in result df

Comment: @AranFreel Ah, okay ... Still not totally sure of all the comparisons, though. As an example, can you take `apple` and `paster` from `df1` and tell me what pairwise comparisons you want?

Comment: DF1 with paster and apple will match in DF2 with the row holding noodle paster because b in DF1 is paster and d in DF2 is paster.  Both values from index 0 column a and b (apple and paster) will compare with all values from column c and d.  Apple will compare with each value from column c and also column d.  Paster will do the same.  After comparing all values the maximum ratio match will then be taken from the DF2 rows and concatenated onto DF1 where the comparison took place (apple and paster)

Comment: @AranFreel Cool, thanks for the clarification. Well, it seems that you could

(1) resign to a loop because you're comparing each element (`apple`) to each entry in a column (everything in `c`), and `apply` doesn't really seem to fit—UNLESS

(2) you Cartesian-join `df1` and `df2`, and then all the comparisons you want to do are in clean rows, and at that point you could proceed with an `apply`. However, with a big dataset, this might be the wrong approach.
Maybe you can edit your question to clarify the comparisons we talked about, and then someone else could chime in!